# Google Maps API v3 - Set destination but leave origin blank?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm setting up the gmaps API for a current project, and would like the map to load as a direction map with the destination set (dynamically populated address), but the origin blank so that the user can quickly/easily put in their own address. All examples I've seen require the origin to be put in as well. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Well you probably only want to get the directions once you've got the user's address.  So just make the call to the directions service once you know that.

Comment: @duncan No, ideally I'd like to have the directions form with the destination already filled, and the origin blank so all the user has to do is input their address and click "Get Directions". If this isn't possible, it adds 2-3 more clicks/steps for the user to just get directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like this:

```js
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function () {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('btnGo').addEventListener('click', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Start: </b>
        <input id="start"/>
        <b>End: </b>
        <select id="end">
            <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
            <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
            <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
            <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
            <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
            <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
            <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
            <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
            <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
            <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
            <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
            <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
        </select>
        <button id="btnGo">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

> Basically it's a customized version of [Directions service sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)
>
> Example: Start: `San Francisco`